# read database from web using SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()

Tags: android, database, sqlite

my android application needs to read from a database on the web and I have just no idea how am I supposed to do it.
I tried the following code:

```
SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cf = new SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory() {

        @Override
        public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery,
                String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
     SQLiteDatabase db =SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("http://dakatora.co.il/locallhost", cf, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

but it throws an exception

can someone please help me?

Comment: can you post your exception, it will give us more information about your problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you implement the database yourself? You need to expose the database through a webservice, and then access it through that. I suggest you read up on webservices. Anyway, I think SQLiteDatabase can  only be used to access a database that is part of your apk.

Comment: @videre do you know any guide that can help me with that?

Comment: Not really, but [here's](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/) something to start with.

Comment: Found this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164373/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-database-with-webservices it deals with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access database directly from an android device (without a lot of hard work and "hackish" ways). You should never use a direct connection to a outside database. Using a web service is a a lot safer.

Also you could try something like this: [Interacting with external SQLite databases from Android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157567/interacting-with-external-sqlite-databases-from-android)